# pattern matching in scala / recursion

Tags: function, scala, design-patterns, recursion, matching

I'd like to implement a function that counts the number of same characters directly following. This function always and only starts at the head.

`function((Char, Int), List[char]) => ((Char, Int), List[Char])`

e.g. `(('b',0), List('b','b','x','x')) => (('b', 2), List('x', 'x'))`

```
  def function: ((Char, Int), List[Char]) => ((Char, Int), List[Char])={
    case(('a', b), Nil) => (('a',b), Nil)
    case(('a', b), t::xs)  => (('a', b), t::xs)
    case (('a', b), a::xs) => function(('a', b+1),xs)
  }
```

I can't find the mistake in my pattern matching.

Are the two characters in the line

```
case (('**a**', b), **a**::xs) => function(('a', b+1),xs)
```

the same (like 'a' == 'a'), when I give them the same character?

thanks!

Comment: Is this a programming language or just some random characters? Just askin'...

Comment: This is scala programming language. Now you also know it ;)

Comment: It was meant to be irony. I know scala and I will never touch it again.

Comment: haha, yes sometimes its kind of strange

Answer (score 4):

I think this does what you want:

```
def function: ((Char, Int), List[Char]) => ((Char, Int), List[Char]) = {
  case ((a, b), Nil) => ((a,b), Nil)
  case ((a, b), c::xs) if a == c => function((a, b+1),xs)
  case other  => other
}
```

Output:

```
scala> function(('a', 0), "aaaabbbcc".toList)
res0: ((Char, Int), List[Char]) = ((a,4),List(b, b, b, c, c))
```

Something simpler might be:

```
def countChar(char: Char, list: List[Char]) : ((Char, Int), List[Char]) = {
  val equalChars = list.takeWhile(_ == char)
  val n = equalChars.length
  ((char, n), list.drop(n))
}
```

Comment: what happens when the character is not at the beginning? E.g., `function(('a', 0), "baaa".toList)`. I think from his description it's not clear what he wants here.

Comment: My solutions don't work in that case, yes. But from _"counts the number of same characters directly following"_ and _"always and only starts at the head"_ I inferred that it should only count the characters at the beginning.

Comment: You are right. The problem is with the question, which is not clear at all. I have already flagged it as "needs revision".

Answer (score 1):

These two cases do the same thing:

```
case (('a', b), t::xs) => ...
case (('a', b), a::xs) => ...
```

They match the 'a' of the tuple, assign the 2nd part of the tuple to `b`, assign the head of the collection to a variable (`t` in the 1st case, `a` in the 2nd) and assign the rest of the collection to `xs`.

Probably not what you had in mind.